# Javascript define a function within event handler

Tags: javascript, html, arrow-functions

How can I write a function within the `onclick` event of a button

What I want to do is something similar to this:

```html
<button onclick="(function(){
     console.log('some code here')
 })">My button</button>
```

Comment: Search for “javascript IIFE” — although it is unclear why such is desired here, as the onclick handler code will already run within its own anonymous function making an IIFE superfluous.

Comment: In modern JS inline JS is discouraged and, if you do use it, normally it's only used to reference a function that exists in a JS script. It's not really clear why you would want to do this.

Comment: I currently use blazor framework and sometimes I wish I could write some quick and easy scripts within the component

Comment: @Andy also, since I am using razor/blazor, I can modify the function per item in a `foreach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to invoke the function:

```html
<button onclick="(function(){
                     console.log('click')
                 })()">My button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button>
onclick="(function(){console.log('click')})()"
>Button 
</button>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.